# How do I overload an operator for a derived type which extends an abstract type?

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I take an example from "Fortran 95/2003 explained" by Metcalf et al, since m own code aims for the same thing.

```
type, abstract :: my_numeric_type
contains
    private
    procedure(op2), deferred :: add
    generic, public :: operator(+) => add
end type

abstract interface
    function op2(a,b) result (r)
        import :: my_numeric_type
        class(my_numeric type), intent(in) :: a,b
        class(my_numeric type), allocatable :: r
    end function op2
end interface

type, extends(my_numeric_type) :: my_integer
    integer, private :: value
contains
    procedure :: add => add_my_integer
end type
```

Now, my question is how do I properly implement the `add_my_integer` function. It seems like I am forced to cast the first argument as `my_integer` since it is a type bound procedure, but the second one has to be `my_numeric_type` to be compliant with the abstract interface. As for the result, should I allocate `r` to `my_integer`? here is what I came up with so far, it does compile, but it seems weird to check for type all the time, and it causes a segmentation fault (perhaps due to some other problem with my code though).

```
function add_my_integer(a,b) result(r)
    class(my_integer), intent(in) :: a
    class(my_numeric_type), intent(in) :: b
    class(my_numeric_type), allocatable :: r

    allocate(my_integer :: r)
    select type (b)
        type is (my_integer)
            r = a+b
    end select
end function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me, but it looks quite complicated (too many `select type`). I made the value public for easy output only, otherwise you want a custom getter and setter.

```
module num

  type, abstract :: my_numeric_type
  contains
      private
      procedure(op2), deferred :: add
      generic, public :: operator(+) => add
      procedure(op), deferred :: ass
      generic, public :: assignment(=) => ass
  end type

  abstract interface
      subroutine op(a,b)
          import :: my_numeric_type
          class(my_numeric_type), intent(out) :: a
          class(my_numeric_type), intent(in) :: b
      end subroutine op
      function op2(a,b) result (r)
          import :: my_numeric_type
          class(my_numeric_type), intent(in) :: a,b
          class(my_numeric_type), allocatable :: r
      end function op2

  end interface

  type, extends(my_numeric_type) :: my_integer
      integer, public :: value
  contains
      procedure :: add => add_my_integer
      procedure :: ass => ass_my_integer
  end type

  contains

    function add_my_integer(a,b) result(r)
        class(my_integer), intent(in) :: a
        class(my_numeric_type), intent(in) :: b
        class(my_numeric_type), allocatable :: r

        select type (b)
            type is (my_integer)
                allocate(my_integer :: r)
                select type (r)
                  type is (my_integer)
                    r%value = a%value+b%value
                end select
        end select
    end function


    subroutine ass_my_integer(a,b)
        class(my_integer), intent(out) :: a
        class(my_numeric_type), intent(in) :: b

        select type (b)
            type is (my_integer)
                    a%value = b%value
        end select
    end subroutine

end module

program main
  use num

  class(my_integer), allocatable :: a, b, c
  allocate(my_integer :: a)
  allocate(my_integer :: b)
  allocate(my_integer :: c)
  a=my_integer(1)
  b=my_integer(2)
  c = a+b
  write (*,*) c%value
end program
```

Comment: It just seems so inefficient to have an "if" statement attached to every operation!

Comment: It seems, but at least the outer one is very necessary, because there can be other extended types you want to add to integer or assign to integer. Try to come up with a better solution to the outer one.

Polymorphism has its costs to efficiency.

Comment: @tiam: it probably wouldn't be too inefficient if your code spends most of its time doing large array operations, which all my Fortran code certainly does.